# EF doesn't Create my table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have three class, using TPH(table per hiracy):

```
abstract class Cat { int Id;    string Name; }
class ItemCat: Cat { }
class PhotoCat: Cat{ }
```

and

```
class Db:DbContext
    {
    Db()
      {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Db,Migrations.Configuration>());
      }
      DbSet<ItemCat> ItemCats;
      DbSet<PhotoCat> PhotoCats;
    }
```

and also have Seed() method to seed ItemCats

update-database run well and seed table.

But EF doesn't create my ItemCat! and insteed it create Cats! & seed it. i don't have cats in DbContext.

I also add [Table("ItemCats")] to ItemCat class, ItemCats table appear but just have id column in it!!

I think it's because ItemCat & PhotoCat classes are empty & just inherit from Cat class.
it's strange for me.

Comment: Have you tested your theory that adding a field to either the ItemCat or PhotoCat classes will result in seperate tables?

Comment: yes. doesn't work. is there any window in IDE to view order of execution of a recercive method?

Comment: Do you mean recursive? Also, can you post your configuration?

Comment: Can you also clarify what your end goal is? What tables would you like to end up with? One for `ItemCat` and one for `PhotoCat`?

Comment: actually my app works well, but it was strange for me that EF Create & seed my ItemCats seed in Cats. yes recursive, found it, stack call

Comment: Is the recursive call you are discussing unrelated to this question? It is not that strange that enabling Table per Heirarchy would result in what you have. Table per Heirarchy means that Entity Framework will generate one table per derived classes. See [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx). Sounds like what you want it TPT - Table Per Type.

Comment: Recursive wasn't belong to this post. right is with you dear @Oren actually i want TPT, i think make mistake. sorry i'm new to code first

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your configuration to **Table Per Type** should give the tables you expect. More details of how table per type generates tables are located [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx).